# What is extern volatile pointer

Tags: c, volatile

What is extern volatile pointer.

```
extern volatile uint32 *ptr;
```

Here, what will be the behavior of *ptr?
What does this actually mean?

And, when it should be used?

I have tried to google about it, but didn't get any satisfactory answer, there is not much info present about this combination.

Comment: You didn't look really hard see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935190/why-is-a-point-to-volatile-pointer-like-volatile-int-p-useful

Comment: Extern and volatile are not related. You have a volatile pointer, and it happens to be defined somewhere else. The extern qualifier doesn't change the semantics of the volatile pointer.

Comment: I have seen extern volatile *ptr usage in the project I am working in, but due to high data security reasons, I can not provide the code, for refernce.
Also, since product is very vast, so I am unable to understand its usage.

Comment: *volatile obj* tells the compiler to read *obj* from its memory location whenever its value is read in the program/scope. Usually the compiler reads small variables (int, pointer) into a CPU register and use that register for the next sequential references to that value (for the sake of efficiency). Using *volatile* makes the compiler stop that behavior.

Comment: Can anyone answer, considering both "exter volatile" please?
I am not looking for individual definitions. 
like what will be the system behaviour if I omit volatile here, what is the behaviour with 'extern volatile'.
any implementaion examples will be helpful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Both *extern* and *volatile* keywords can be considered independently. The role of each of these keywords does not interact with the other one, and thus an explanation of each of them can be detailed independently, as below.

**extern** tells the compiler that the actual definition of *ptr* is in another module (another `.c`). Basically, there is no much change to how the compiler handles *ptr* - having *extern* just tells the compiler that it does not have to reserve some space in memory for *ptr* as it is done elsewhere in another `.c`, and its actual memory location will be given by the *linker* later.

```
  extern uint32 *ptr;
```

If you omit *extern* the compiler will not complain. However, later, the *linker*, when it tries to link all object modules in order to build the final executable program, will throw an error saying "*ptr* is defined twice" (since it is already defined in another `.c`).

```
  uint32 *ptr;
```

**volatile** tells the compiler that the memory location where *ptr* resides may be altered / modified by some external event, and it (the compiler) should not rely on some efficiency optimizations like considering that the value of *ptr* will not change during the scope of a few sequential lines of C. Such an event may be an asynchronous interruption, that happens when the CPU executes the above said scope, and modifies the *ptr* value.

Typically (with virtual assembly code of optimized C in comments), REGx are CPU registers, and we are not much interested in the variable *y*...

```
  int x = 10;

  int func() {
    int y;              // REG4
    printf("%d\n", x);  // Set REG3 = memory(x) and display x
    x += 2;             // Add 2 to REG3
    y = x * x;          // REG4 = REG3 * REG3
    printf("%d %d\n", x, y); // Do printf(..., REG3, REG4)
    x += 5;             // REG3 = REG3 + 5
                        // memory(x) = REG3 (save register to memory)
    return y;           // return REG4
  }
```

should display `10, 12, 144`. For the sake of efficiency (memory accesses are more costly than register accesses) say the compiler stores the value of *x* in an internal CPU register (REG3) and uses it in *func* safely until the end where it stores the new value of *x* (it's a global var) to *x* memory location. *x* is 17 at the end.

But imagine the program is more complex than that and has a clock interruption every minute that subtract 10 to *x*. What happens if an interruption...

```
  void inter_call_by_timer_every_minute() {
     x -= 10;
  }
```

... occurs in *func* say just after the `printf("%d\n", x);` line? *func* has *x* in REG3 (10), add 2 (12) and finally add 5 (17) and stores the REG3 result to *x* memory location (17). This is wrong as the interruption effect (-10) has been hidden by the compiler optimization, since it stores the value from REG3 to memory(x) at the end ignoring the *subtract* done by the interruption. The correct result was: *x* is initially 10, interrupt subtract 10 to it (0) after the first `printf` in *func*, then 2 is added, then 5. Result 7.

Adding *volatile*

```
  volatile int x = 10;
```

will have the compiler avoid the *x* optimizations in *func*

```
  int func() {
    int y;              // REG4
    printf("%d\n", x);  // display memory(x)
    x += 2;             // memory(x) += 2
    y = x * x;          // REG4 = memory(x) * memory(x)
    printf("%d %d\n", x, y); // Do printf(..., memory(x), REG4)
    x += 5;             // memory(x) += 5
    return y;           // return REG4
  }
```

and read the value of *x* from memory all the time. Result, having an interruption from *inter_call_by_timer_every_minute* after the first printf, is *x* == 7.

Comment: It should be noted that there is no guarantee in the C standard that operators like `+=` are atomic, and `x * x` is certainly not atomic. So while `volatile` indeed tells the compiler not to cache reads, it won't do anything regarding atomicity. Furthermore, in this case, adding `volatile` might cause `y` *not* to end up being a square of any integer number, if `x -= 10` happens between two reads in `x * x`. This is possibly even a worse outcome than skipping a single timer decrement.

Answer (score 2):

I would explain the way I know through the keywords. `extern` means the variable is defined for use somewhere outside the definition scope. For example it could be defined in header file and get used in .c file.

`volatile` means that modification of that variable should be consistent to the external world. This means that all update should be committed to the main memory so that it can be seen by other threads which share the same execution space.

Answer (score 2):

`extern` keyword is used to declare a global variable which is defined somewhere else (that means its defined in some other `.c` file).

For example consider in a project two `.c` files `a.c` and `b.c` are there. In that a global variable is defined in `a.c`, and that variable can be accessed in all the functions which are defined in that file. If we want to access that same global variable in our second file `b.c`, then that variable should be declared as `extern` in `b.c`

`a.c` file is given below

```
int flag = 0;
int main()
{
    .......
    func1();
    printf("\nflag value is %d\n", flag).
    ....... 
}
```

`b.c` file is given below

```
extern int flag;
void func1();
{
    .....
    flag = 10;
    .....
}
```

`volatile` keyword is used to inform the compiler to avoid doing any sort of optimization while generating executable instructions.

```
int flag = 0;
int main()
{
    while(flag == 0);
    printf("\nflag value is %d\n", flag);
    return 0;

}
```

Consider the above program, all compiler will optimize the `while(flag == 0);` as `while(1);`. Because in the code there is no where `flag` value gets updated before that `while` loop. So if that variable value gets updated by some other hardware then it will never get reflected in the program execution. So if we declare that variable as `volatile` like below, compiler will not perform any optimization for that variable, and the behviour of that program will be as intended.

```
volatile int flag = 0;
```

But if there is no way for the value of program's variable is getting updated by other hardware, then no need to declare that variable as `volatile`. Because for valatile variables, CPU needs to perform I/O operation for each instructions which is accessing that variable. This impact in performance needs to be consider for a variable which will never get updated by other hardwares.

Answer (score 0):

Extern means it is defined elsewhere - probably in the header file.
Volatile is info for the compiler that it shouldn't try to optimize this.

Comment: Probably _not_ in a header file, it is uncommon to define variables in header files and most of the time also bad practice. You will likely find extern in the header filer and the actual definition in a corresponding C file.