# volatile pointer to function showing compile error when using without typedef; need help w/ "void (* volatile userFunc)(void)"

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, volatile, pointer-to-member

I'm writing an Arduino library using C++ classes. Inside the class, I have a private member variable which is a pointer to a function.

The problem is that I need the pointer to be volatile since the pointer to the function will be set *outside* an ISR, and can be changed during program execution, but the function will be called *inside* an ISR. Hence, I think I need a volatile pointer to a nonvolatile function, is that right?

Anyway, what I'm doing is creating a mechanism for allowing a custom user function which will be called periodically by my library.

Here's the basics:

This just shows the essential parts for you to see.

.h file

```
class myLib
{
  public:
  void attachOverflowInterrupt(void (*myFunc)());

  private:
  volatile void (*userOverflowFunction)(void);
}
```

.cpp file

```
void myLib::attachOverflowInterrupt(void (*myFunc)())
{
  //ensure atomic access
  uint8_t SREGbak = SREG; //back up interrupt state
  noInterrupts(); //interrupts off

  userOverflowFunction = myFunc; //attach function //<--the part that matters to my problem here

  SREG = SREGbak; //restore interrupt state 
}

//inside the interrupt, their function is called essentially like this:
this->userOverflowFunction();
```

Arduino .ino file (only essential parts shown)

```
void doSomething()
{
}

myLib1.attachOverflowInterrupt(doSomething);
```

THIS CODE DOES NOT compile. I get this error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)()' to 'volatile void (*)()' [-fpermissive] userOverflowFunction = myFunc; //attach function
```

If I do this in the class instead, however, it compiles:

```
class myLib
{
  public:
  void attachOverflowInterrupt(void (*myFunc)());
  //volatile void (*userOverflowFunction)(void); //compile error
  void (* volatile userOverflowFunction)(void); //<---compiles
}
```

OR, if I do this instead, it compiles:

```
typedef void (*voidFuncPtr)(void);

class myLib
{
  public:
  void attachOverflowInterrupt(void (*myFunc)());
  //volatile void (*userOverflowFunction)(void); //compile error
  //void (* volatile userOverflowFunction)(void); //compiles
  volatile voidFuncPtr userOverflowFunction; //<---compiles
}
```

So, what is the difference between these three things that makes the first one fail but the latter 2 compile?

```
volatile void (*userOverflowFunction)(void); //compile error
void (* volatile userOverflowFunction)(void); //compiles
volatile voidFuncPtr userOverflowFunction; //compiles
```

Background reading I have done:

1. http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/C-Volatile-Keyword
2. [Why is a point-to-volatile pointer, like "volatile int * p", useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935190/why-is-a-point-to-volatile-pointer-like-volatile-int-p-useful)

Additional question:

The 1st background link above states:
"Volatile pointers to non-volatile data are very rare (I think I've used them once), but I'd better go ahead and give you the syntax:"

```
int * volatile p;
```

So, when would you use this above technique? In my case?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "non-volatile function". Except for non-static class member functions, functions cannot be qualified. (And even for NSMFs, the qualification applies to the implicit instance argument and not to the function itself.)

Comment: Compiler errors are *printed.* Not 'thrown'. And there is a *major* difference between not working and not compiling.

Comment: @KerrekSB, follow-up question: My barrgroup source above shows how to make a "volatile pointer to non-volatile data" like this: "int * volatile p;". That is what I'm doing with the function in my 1st example that compiles. Makes sense (even though in my case, the function can't be "non-volatile" nor "volatile." Barrgroup also shows how to make a "volatile pointer to a volatile variable" like this: "int volatile * volatile p;". Since functions can't be volatile, is it correct to say that there IS NO POINTER-TO-A-FUNCTION EQUIVALENT for the latter of the two Barrgroup examples just mentioned?

Comment: Functions are not data. Functions are not variables. Functions are a separate kind of entity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem**

The statement `volatile void (*userOverflowFunction)(void);` says that you have a pointer to a function returning a type `volatile void`.

While a `volatile void` is rather conceptual (*it's easier to understand what a `volatile int` is*), it is yet a valid return type, and it doesn't match the return type of `doSomething()` .

**The solution**

You said that you wanted the pointer to be volatile.

Translating this in C++ gives: `void (* volatile userOverflowFunction)(void);` and here you have your first finding.

THe second finding you describe corresponds to defining a function pointer type,  and then says it's a volatile pointer of that type.  Both are equivalent.

**Edit: additional remarks**

The approach that you use is perfectly logic:  your function is not volatile (as Kerrek already pointed out in the comments),  but your interupt handler needs to get the value of the pointer which might have been changed in a volatile manner.

You may also be interested in reading about [`std::signal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal).  As your function pointer is not a `volatile std::sig_atomic_t`, you should consider making it atomic, using your second approach:   `std::atomic<voidFuncPtr> userOverflowFunction;`

Comment: Christophe, great answer. Thank you! The placement of volatile to make the pointer volatile was what confused me so much. It never occurred to me that you could have a volatile datatype returned by a function, either, as I've never needed that before.

Comment: As for ensuring atomic access, this code is running on an 8-bit Atmel AVR microcontroller (ATmega328), and the available C library is defined in AVR-Libc. I don't have access to std::signal as far as I know. Rather, the way atomic access is ensured is by disabling interrupts. I went ahead and added the code back into my question to demonstrate this. Also, AVR-libc provides an atomic block macro to ensure atomic read-write access here: http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__atomic.html. Inside ISRs, however, interrupts are automatically disabled upon entering....